# Place an image Icon on Line in three.js

Tags: three.js, mapping

I've drawn a line using list of xyz points as follows

```js
for (var i = 0, len = vertices.length - 1; i < len; i++) {
        vertex = vertices[i];
        geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(width+7, height, 1);
        geometry.computeVertexNormals(); 
        //material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff3333, shading: THREE.FlatShading, wireframe: true, transparent: true });            
        //Initializing MeshNormalMaterial to get the 3d Line Geometry
        material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xEB9180 });
       
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        mesh.position = vertex;
        mesh.lookAt(vertices[1 + i]);
        length = vertex.distanceTo(vertices[1 + i]);
        mesh.scale.set(1, 1, length + width);
        mesh.translateZ(0.5 * length);
        segments.add(mesh);
    }
```

Line which is created dynamically with list of xyz points:

[image]

Now I want to place an image icon on the **line** which should traverse the entire line as follows

[image]

Comment: And then ? Tell what you have tried and ask a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use a `THREE.Sprite()` object for your icon. You can give it a texture.

As for moving it along the line, just adjust the Sprite's `.position` value to follow your vertices array. I leave the speed management up to you!

Comment: function DisplayIconByXYZ(x, y, z) {
    // scene.remove(prevCube);
    var map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("./images/arrow.png");
    var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({ map: map, color: 0xffffff, fog: true });
    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(material);
    sprite.position.set(x, y, z);
    scene.add(sprite);
}

Comment: Simplify -- remove the references to the texture, just call `var sprite = new THREE.Sprite();` and see -- does it appear as a white square? Is the scale correct for your application? It might be too small or too large to use.  If it appears, try adding back the texture. Why are you applying fog?